# NSString sizeWithFont inverted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit

we have this function:

```
CGSize size = [cell.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.textLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(cellWidth, FLT_MAX)];
```

Can we use it inverted?
I want to see text, which can be in this size with my font.
Have you any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "inverted"?

Comment: I want to see number of symbols for nsstring with my size and font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found great solution:

```
- (NSString*)stringVisibleInRect:(CGRect)rect inString:(NSString *)string {
    NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *testString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *visibleString = @"";
    for (int i = 0; i < [words count] && [words count] > 0; i++)
    {
        NSString *newString = (NSString *)[words objectAtIndex:i];
        testString =[testString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ ",newString];

        CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, 9999);

        CGSize stringSize = [testString sizeWithFont:font
                                   constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                                       lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        if (stringSize.height > rect.size.height) // || stringSize.width > rect.size.width)
            break;

        visibleString = testString;
    }
    words = nil;
    return visibleString;
}
```

Comment: That should work, actually it's probably a safer bet if your goal is to measure how much is visible in a `UILabel` as i would guess the `sizeWithFont:` methods use the same font code as a `UILabel`. If require  more exact font control i recommend you use CoreText for both measuring and rendering, but as you have seen the API is quite low level.

Comment: I am using drawInRect and it's working good. Very simple way.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints`? It can be used to get range of text visible assuming certain constraints.

Comment: The CoreText API is very chatty and verbose so it would take a while to write an example, but take a look at https://github.com/wader/ios-misc/blob/master/CoreTextLabel/CoreTextLabel.m the adjust font size code makes use of it to see if the whole text fits.

Comment: I've found that it returns CGSize, but I don't need it. I want to see only text length.

Comment: Yeah but you can ignore the return value and pass a pointer to a `CFRange` as the `fitRange` argument. From the documentation about  `fitRange`: "On return, contains the range of the string that actually fit in the constrained size."

Comment: I don't understand you. My code: `CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef) string);`
    `CGSize textSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0,0), NULL, textRect.size, NULL);` How can I found NSRange?

Comment: Declare a `CFRange fitRange;` and then use `&fitRange` as fitRange argument. A problem is that you will probably not get the exact character range that the `UILabel` is actually showing as im not sure `UILabel` actually use CoreText for drawing. But you can probably get a quite good approximation by "converting" the `UILabel` styles and attributes to CoreText styles and attributes and then use `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints`.

Comment: like this: `CFRange *range;`
    `NSAttributedString *string = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:nil] autorelease];`
    `CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef) string);`
    `CGSize textSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0,0), NULL, textRect.size, &range);`
    `NSLog(@"range: %@", range);` ? range = null.